# How to run multiple slave batch files from a master batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a special requirement where I am trying to run child bat files from a master bat file. But there are multiple issues that I am running into.

1. Master does not wait for child to get completed and completes without waiting for child file completion. Which means I can not schedule it as job.
2. When I am doing parallel execution inside master file, it does not go to the next line of execution.

I am adding a reference code for you.

Code for Master file:-

```
start "C:\Test\Parallel_batch_process\chlidA.bat"
start "C:\Test\Parallel_batch_process\chlidB.bat"
```

ChildA:-

```
start "test1" cmd.exe /C ^(ping server1 -n 2 ^> C:\Test\Parallel_batch_process\Test1.txt^) 
start "test2" cmd.exe /C ^(ping server2 -n 2 ^> C:\Test\Parallel_batch_process\Test2.txt^)
```

ChildB:-

```
start "test1" cmd.exe /C ^(ping Server3 -n 5 ^> C:\Test\Parallel_batch_process\Test3.txt^)
start "test2" cmd.exe /C ^(ping Server4 -n 2 ^> C:\Test\Parallel_batch_process\Test4.txt^)
```

There is one more extension to this where I am calling GrandChild from the Child files, but for if this much only works then I can go for the next level.

Comment: It's unclear what you asking. You want that the master wait for each child but you also want to run them parallel, you can't get both at the same time

Comment: `start "C:\Test\Parallel_batch_process\chlidA.bat"`  
`start "C:\Test\Parallel_batch_process\chlidB.bat"`
"child" is spelled incorrectly in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute a batch file from within another, you should use the `CALL` command:

```
REM Child.bat
ECHO This is the child
```

.

```
REM Master.bat
ECHO This is the master
CALL Child.bat
CALL Child.bat
```

Comment: Thanks it has worked to a certain extent, please also let me know the answer for the first part of the question. Which asks for master batch file to be active unless child completes their processing. This looks to be sequential execution how to perform parallel execution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have finally understood your question - correct me if I am wrong. You want to:

1. Start a batch file that starts a number of new batch files, all running simultaneously;
2. Yet this batch file does not finish until all the started batch files have themselves finished.

In other words, you want to `JOIN` to the running processes that this batch file started, waiting for all of them to finish until they themselves have finished.

Yeah, you can't do that. Unfortunately, DOS (which is where batch files started!) doesn't have the concept of parallel execution. So what you need to do is start each of the processes independently, and then use the `tasklist` command to find out if they're still running (since Windows XP).

```
tasklist
```

This outputs the data in a pretty format, suitable for display - but not for processing! Let's change the format, by choosing the Comma-Separated Values (CSV) version:

```
tasklist /fo CSV
```

Now we're talking! But there are still headers. Let's remove those:

```
tasklist /nh /fo CSV
```

Hmmm. OK, but *ALL* the processes that are running are listed. Can we be selective? Yes, by using the `if` clause (spelled `fi`):

```
tasklist /nh /fo CSV /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"
```

> The `if` test checks the name of the running program. You haven't told us that, so I've used `cmd.exe` - a bad idea! (I assume you could be running your own shells?) Note that there are a number of attributes - try `windowname` if that helps...

Now we can do some processing! You can find out how many are running using `find`'s `-c` option:

```
tasklist /nh /fo CSV /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" | find /c "cmd"
```

But that's not very helpful for processing. So:

```
for /f "usebackq" %%F in (`tasklist /nh /fo CSV /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" ^| find /c "cmd"`) do set NUM=%%F
```

> Don't forget: on the command line, `for` uses one `%`. In a batch file, you need two of them: `%%`
>   Also: use the escape character `^` for special shell characters...

So now you've got the number of your processes that are running in the `NUM` variable:

```
:Wait
for /f "usebackq" ... (rest of line)
if %NUM% NEQ 0 goto Wait
```

...but that's a little processor intensive! You should probably wait a little while between the two lines:

```
:Wait
for /f "usebackq" ... (rest of line above)
if %NUM% EQU 0 goto Exit
timeout 1 > nul
goto Wait
:Exit
```

Comment: Those are not running in DOS so obviously they have the ability to run in parallel. Windows cmd is not DOS

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, but I said that batch files were _started_ in DOS, so it still has many of those concepts weighing it down. There is no `JOIN` concept...

Comment: I think I got your point now. You mean the history of batch is from DOS era so it has legacy issues. I thought you mean the above batch file was called from DOS